# Display: inline-block não está alinhando os textos

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando alinhar 3 palavras usando o display: inline-block. Mas elas não estão ficando alinhadas, já reescrevi o código olhei e nada, alguém tem ideia do porquê isso está acontecendo ?. Quero alinhar a parte "Início Cardápio Contato"

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Elvis Alencar Delivery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Topo do site, menu -->

<div class='one'></div>
<header class='header'>
    <div class='container'>
        <a href='index.html' class='grid-4'>
            <img src="#" alt="logo do Elvis Alencar Delivery"/>
        </a>
    
    <nav class='grid-12 topo'>
        <ul>
            
            <li><a href='index.html'>Início</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Cardápio</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Contato</a></li>

        </ul>
    
    
    </nav>

    </div>

</header>

<!-- Fim do menu -->
</body>
</html>
```

O style do css.

```css
.one {
 width: 100%;
 height: 4px;
 background: #f2e41b;

}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#d90404;
    padding: 25px;
    
}

.topo {
    text-align: right;
}

.topo ul il {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Oi, você viu que você escreveu errado o "li"? Você escreveu assim: ".topo ul il".
Qualquer coisa tente colocar só Display Inline. :)
Se não der certo, tente colocar o Display Inline só no ".topo ul".
O Display Flex resolveria isso também. :)

Comment: Eu vi agora kkkkkkkk, que erro besta. Muito obrigado =)